# Upgrading CPU made Ubuntu slow

Tags: 20.04, cpu

I upgraded cpu 3900x to 5950x and the main Ubuntu 20 guest machine I am using became slow. I see tearing when dragging window.

I have 128GB of ram 80dedicated to this guest. Storage is on NVME.

Comment: downgrade the cpu.

Comment: @petep Maybe it's the thermal paste or some other minor mechanical problem in which case downgrading the CPU wouldn't help.

Comment: I can not downgrade it, I am already using the previous cpu. I found a beefy cooler for it NH D15. sensors shows Tctl:         +48.4°C  Tccd1:        +34.2°C  Tccd2:        +32.5°C.
Will try booting directly into ubuntu to check if it is specific to VM.